# Задача на поиск времени c++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Дано время в 3х переменных (H - часы, M - минуты, S - секунды), нужно найти количество секунд до **ближайшего следующего** времени 11:11:11, задача вроде простая, но когда дается время больше(например 12:11:11) не понимаю как это сделать, написал такой код, пытался найти время даже если оно больше, но судя по всему где-то ошибся. Помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста.

Пример ввода-вывода:

Ввод:

11 10 10

Вывод : 61(Секунд до следующего ближайшего времени 11 11 11)

Мой код :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    int h = 0, m = 0, s = 0, ans = 0;

    inp >> h >> m >> s;

    if (h == m && m == s && s == 11) {
        otp << 86400;
    }
    else {
        if (h <= 11 && m <= 11 && s < 11) {
            otp << (((11 - h) * 3600) + ((11 - m) * 60) + 11 - s);
        }
        else {
            otp << 86400 - (((3600 * h) + (60 * m) + s) - ((3600 * 11) + (60 * 11) + 11));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (h <= 11 && m <= 11 && s < 11) {` - кхм, кхм, это что за фигня?

Comment: @Igor проверка на то если время раньше 11 11 11

Comment: Ну и что, 9:15 утра *позже* 11:11:11? :)

Comment: @Harry посмеялся)) Просто сижу решаю задачи уже часов 5-6 к ряду, пора заканчивать, устал...

Comment: @Harry можете с этим помочь, задача потяжелее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916573/Задача-объеденение-филий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так?

```
const int T = 11*3600+11*60+11;
int t = h*3600+m*60+s;

if (t < T) 
    otp << T-t;
else
    otp << T+86400-t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
targetSeconds = 11 * 3600 + 11 * 60 + 11;
inputSeconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;

result = targetSeconds - inputSeconds;
if (result <= 0)
  result = result + 86400;
```