# Задача: объединение филий С++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

> **Задача**
>
> С целью оптимизации компания решила соединить 4 филии в одну. Соответственно и объединить их счета в банке(У каждой филии свой счет). Банк может перевести все деньги с одного счета на другой и закрыть пустой счет. За такую операции банк берет процент от суммы объединенных счетов, который списывается с объединенного счета.
>
> Вам положено рассчитать сколько денег будет на счету объединенной филии.
>
> Внимание! От последовательности закрытия банковских счетов зависит размер процента, его нужно минимизировать.

Я написал код, (Таких задачи было 2, для задачи с 3-мя филиями такой способ работает) не могу понять что делаю не так, вроде процент не может быть меньше если соединять их

Суть кода : ввод кол-ва денег 4х филий, ввод процента.Сортировка по кол-ву денег. Выбор самого лучшего варианта(самая маленькая сумма). Вбрасываю самый лучший вариант в `g[]`, сортирую еще раз, и применяю способ для 3х филий. Проходит только несколько тестов, что с кодом не так? Где и в чем ошибки?

P.S. [Есть еще такой код, проходит больше тестов](https://ideone.com/9qddzW)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    double ans = 0, p = 0;

    vector<int> g(4);

    inp >> g[0] >> g[1] >> g[2] >> g[3] >> p;

    sort(g.begin(), g.end());

    ans = (g[0] + g[1]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    g[1] = ans;

    g.erase(g.begin());

    sort(g.begin(), g.end());

    ans = (g[0] + g[1]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    ans = (ans + g[2]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    otp << fixed << setprecision(2) << ans;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было поменять тип вектора, туда может попасть вещественное число. Устранил ошибку - работающий код :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    double ans = 0, p = 0;

    vector<double> g(4);

    inp >> g[0] >> g[1] >> g[2] >> g[3] >> p;

    sort(g.begin(), g.end());

    ans = (g[0] + g[1]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    g[1] = ans;

    g.erase(g.begin());

    sort(g.begin(), g.end());

    ans = (g[0] + g[1]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    ans = (ans + g[2]) * (1 - (p / 100));

    otp << fixed << setprecision(2) << ans;

    return 0;
}
```